# How can I use a function say digits with Spring JPA and native query and DB2

Tags: spring-boot, jdbc, spring-data-jpa, db2

I want to be able to use this function and them pass the parameter.  But I get this error, it is almost that spring jpa or java prepared statements are not allowing me to do this.

The code looks like the following in the logs.

```
Hibernate: UPDATE DB2PROD.GLOBAL_TABLE
```

SET CONTRACT_ID = DIGITS( ? )
WHERE GLOBAL_ID = ?

```
@Query(value = "UPDATE DB2PROD.GLOBAL_TABLE \n" +
        " SET CONTRACT_ID = DIGITS( :indicator ) \n" +
        "   WHERE GLOBAL_ID = :id ", nativeQuery = true)
int update(final Integer indicator, final String id);
```

And the error:

> 2022-03-11 15:54:25.982  WARN 95241 --- [   scheduling-1]
> o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: -418, SQLState:
> 42610 2022-03-11 15:54:25.982 ERROR 95241 --- [   scheduling-1]
> o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : DB2 SQL Error:
> SQLCODE=-418, SQLSTATE=42610, SQLERRMC=null, DRIVER=4.25.13 2022-03-11
> 15:54:25.982  WARN 95241 --- [   scheduling-1]
> o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: -516, SQLState:
> 26501 2022-03-11 15:54:25.983 ERROR 95241 --- [   scheduling-1]
> o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : DB2 SQL Error:
> SQLCODE=-516, SQLSTATE=26501, SQLERRMC=null, DRIVER=4.25.13 2022-03-11
> 15:54:25.983  WARN 95241 --- [   scheduling-1]
> o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: -518, SQLState:
> 07003 2022-03-11 15:54:25.983 ERROR 95241 --- [   scheduling-1]
> o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : DB2 SQL Error:
> SQLCODE=-518, SQLSTATE=07003, SQLERRMC=null, DRIVER=4.25.13 2022-03-11
> 15:54:26.017 ERROR 95241 --- [   scheduling-1]
> c.p.p.m.contacts.service.ContactService  : Error on save contact

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Db2 can't determine a data type of the parameter in the `DIGITS (?)` expression.
You must define it explicitly with `CAST` like:
`DIGITS (CAST (? AS INT))`
or
`DIGITS (CAST (? AS DEC (5)))`
etc.

Comment: This worked in terms of digit and cast